# ?Watson Speech to text limitations : comments?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

- no support for the AAC format
- meetings are several hours long : Lossless format FLAC generates very large files (more than accepted by the API set at 100 MB)
- One hour test meeting = 210 MB in FLAC and 30 MB in OPUS. Hence need to go for OPUS (lossy format ) and not FLAC (lossless)
- Text hard to read for Humans (punctuation )
- No indication of low confidence on words (which could indicate a potential error)
- lots of "empty" moments

PLUS
Not bad for a demo ... How can we achieve a production grad system ?

Comment: It's not clear what your specific questions are. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback, here are some answers:

- You say that one hour in FLAC is 210 MBS? what sampling rate are you using? and bits per sample? Pleae note that you can downsample to 16Khz with no loss in accuracy, that will result in much smaller files.
- IBM is working on prettifying the output, stay tuned...
- There is confidence for each word, you just need to pass the "word_confidence=true" parameter when using the WebSockets or REST api
- "empty moments"? what do you mean

We will be happy to help you build a production system. What is your use case?

Dani

Answer (score 0):

Just general text-to-speech considerations:

1. People frequently speak over top of each other
2. Sensitive to the quality of environment being captured (acoustics of room, placement of recording device(s), phone call-ins, etc)
3. Technical/Domain specific words are misclassified (emerging technology is often too new to be in training set)
4. Classification of non-native speakers is difficult